# Trying to get border to stay on bottom

Tags: css

Soo ive tried this code

```
.itemselected {
Width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}
```

But when i use that it loks very weird like theres a border around the Whole thing, i only want the border at the bottom.

Comment: Can you supply a fiddle to demonstrate what you get?

Comment: Yeah i can submit one soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.itemselected {
Width: 150px;
height: 150px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
border-top: 0;
border-left: 0;
border-right: 0;
}
```

That should fix it, i had the same problem before but when i used that code to set the other borders to 0 it worked perfectly :)

Comment: Thank you sir, but why do i have to sett the others to 0? cant i just do the code whit out them shouldnt that work too normaly?

Comment: @JonasDerminste Im not quit sure abaout that but i hope this worked for you :)